# ActiveRecord Validations with Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models `User` and `Organization` with association like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :organization
  ...
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :users
  ...
end
```

And, `User` has a username field. I want to validate the uniqueness of username within a particular organization.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please accet my answer if it is worked for you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with `scope` parameter of [**`validates_uniqueness_of`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of).

In your `user.rb`,write this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_name, scope: :organization_id
end
```